# How can I reduce the CSS to a few properties

Tags: php, css, regex, less

How can I reduce the CSS/(or)LESS with PHP?
From this:

```
.header-logo-holder{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@rw-header-background-color, 10%);
    .logo{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .eg-clearfix();
}
```

To this:

```
.header-logo-holder{
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@rw-header-background-color, 10%);
}
```

I want to leave only the rules color, background and border.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have the first css, but want to remove some lines via PHP?

Comment: Why do you want to remove CSS with PHP? If your CSS/Less is separate (which it should be), you can just remove the CSS, in the CSS/Less.

Comment: I found a solution, but the problem is the `.logo { ... }` part.

But why do you want to do this ?

Comment: forever, I want to minimize the CSS to only colors. That would let me to create a different color scheme, without touching other styles.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```php
<?php

//give the file (string) to the function
function keepColorBackgroundBorder($input) {

    //didn't check if the input was correct (string, not empty, etc)

    //we turn the input into an array
    $input = explode("\n", $input);

    //here is the list of strings which must be in a line to keep it in our final string
    $keep = ['{', '}', 'color', 'background', 'border'];

    $result = '';

    //foreach over the lines of the input
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

        //foreach over each characters we want to keep
        foreach ($keep as $key => $value2) {

            //if the characters are somewhere in the line
            if (strpos($value, $value2) !== false) {

                //we add the line + a newline character
                $result .= $value . "\n";

                //we stop the check for characters as we don't want a line to be included twice
                //e.g: border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@rw-header-background-color, 10%);
                //this example contains border and background
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //we return the result, end delete the last newline character
    return trim($result);
}

//we get the file as a string
$input = file_get_contents('file.css');

//we call the function and we look at what was outputted
echo keepColorBackgroundBorder($input);
```

There is probably too much comments, but it's better too much than not enough.

I used an array so that it is easy to change if you want to. For example, you could have `['background:', 'border:', 'border-bottom:']` etc to be sure that a line is not included if it contains an allowed word somewhere else than at the start, like `border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@rw-header-background-color, 10%);` which contains `background`, but not `background:`.

If `file.css` contains:

```
.header-logo-holder{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@rw-header-background-color, 10%);
    .logo{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .eg-clearfix();
}
```

You will get:

```
.header-logo-holder{
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@rw-header-background-color, 10%);
    .logo{
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks good enough. I have found a solution myself as well, but it still requires some elements to removed manually. It is very similar to yours. :) Thank you for help, anyways. ;) Cheers.

Comment: @Smartik Happy to help. Edited my answer to add some details. I don't know *LESS*, but I don't think that `.logo { }` is not actually a problem.